# How to make UICollectionViewCell's width auto resize and its height stay the same

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want my custom `UICollectionViewCell`'s `width` dynamically changes depending on the `UILabel` content inside, but each cell should stay the same height. Using `estimatedItemSize` will also change the `height` value (which isn't what I want, I need it to stay the same, say 30.) 
And after reloading data for several times it starts being like an chaos, making some cells not vertical align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by using **sizeWithAttributes** in **sizeForItemAtIndexPath** to dynamically determine the width of each cell should be.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try implementing

```
collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Comment: Yes I tried, the issue is that I need auto-resizing of the cell's width.

Comment: Is the resize triggered by the cell itself?